# Navigation controller push nil view controller error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having some problems with a Navigation controller in my app. Moving from the RootViewController to a UITableViewController works fine. I now want to have one more level of drilldown, so users pick an item from the list and a new screen appears, like this:

`RootViewController --> TableViewController --> ItemViewController`

I've used the exact same code that switches the first views, but I get:

`Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController...`

The code is identical to the first one, so how can it be nil?

In RootViewController.h:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet TableViewController *tableViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) TableViewController * tableViewController;
```

In the .m file I synthesize the property and then use a button to call:

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];`

In TableViewController.h:

```
#import "ItemDetailViewController.h"

@class TableViewController;

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {
    IBOutlet ItemDetailViewController * itemDetailViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ItemDetailViewController * itemDetailViewController;

@end
```

And again, I synthesize it in the .m file and use code to push the new view in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:itemDetailViewController animated:YES];`

When you tap on an item I get the error message above. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is the connection between 'itemDetailViewController' and 'plantDetailViewController'?

Comment: Sorry, typo! Changed the names to make it easier to read.

Comment: 3 nibs, one for each view. RootViewController, TableViewController, ItemViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most common cause of this error is failing to connect `itemDetailViewController` to the actual object in IB. Note that you should generally place the `IBOutlet` designator on the property rather than on the ivar.

Comment: Everything is connected up as per the RootViewController, and all connections are there and correct. I will however switch the IBOutlet designators, maybe its that?

Comment: In the debugger, is `itemDetailViewController` nil? Is it nil in `TableViewController viewDidLoad`? If so, then you're not connected to what you think you're connected to.

Comment: How can I check that? Do you mean use instruments and check for memory allocation?

Comment: Okay just did an if statement to check if self.itemDetailViewController is nil, and it is. Any idea why? Everything is definitely connected up the same as the first view.

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint and `po itemDetailViewController`. A common reason is that your NIB has not loaded yet (`viewDidLoad` has not run). This doesn't happen until the view is first accessed. Another common mistake is having duplicate objects. This commonly happens when people wire an object in the NIB and also create an object of the same class using `+alloc`. The two objects are unrelated. Another possibility is that you're not loading the NIB you think you are. Put breakpoints in `-viewDidLoad` and see when things happen.

Comment: One more mistake: make sure that your View Controller object IB actually references the correct "other" NIB.

Comment: What doesn't make sense though is that everything is connected up correctly, and if it works in the first two views (RootViewController and TableViewController) why does it not work using the same connections, settings etc? There literally is nothing different apart from obviously which connections I've made. Funnily enough, instantiating an object and specifying the NIB seems to work. However, you're telling me here that doing this causes the error, I'm really lost as to why, even with identical connections etc, the 3rd view doesn't work.